# Where to put airflow_local_settings.py in Composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

In composer (airflow 1.10.10), is it possible to create an `airflow_local_settings.py` file? And if so where should it be stored? I need this as I need an initContainer for my pod.

> Add a airflow_local_settings.py file to your $PYTHONPATH or to $AIRFLOW_HOME/config folder.

For me, the above statement is unclear for Cloud-composer, as this config folder in an env bucket would probably not be synced with a worker.

Comment: In 1.10.11 and higher, you can send initcontainers straight to the KubernetesPodOperator. But I don't see a clear way of doing the same thing in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

`airflow_local_settings.py` can be provided into `dags` folder in Composer GCS bucket according to [Airflow initialization](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-1-stable/airflow/settings.py#L364) implementation where DAGs folder is added to sys.path before the configuration folder (`$AIRFLOW_HOME/config`). Keep in mind that by doing so you are overriding the Composer default policies.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Slack discussions in the Apache Airflow Community Slack. It is not supported yet.